# How to create grid view in Yii2 (after clicking on particular id from list open all detail of that id )?

Tags: php, yii2

In index.php of Member module I have write this widget to open detail after click on id.but here open a Url code as it is not url page.please give me solution. and suggestion what i use because i am not familiar with Yii2.

```
             <?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
               [
                   'label'=>'practiceCode',
                   'format' => 'url',
                   'value'=>function ($data) {
                   return Html::a(Html::encode("View"),'practice/view');
                },
            ],


                    'memberCode',
                    'firstName',
                    'lastName',
                    'email:email',
                    'mobile',

                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                ],
            ]); ?>
```

Comment: refer [Url :: to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail) to write custom URl.

Comment: Thanks,But i got answer.using 'format'=>raw Instead of 'format'=>url .

Comment: Can i use href link instead of 'label'=>'practiceCode', because my css will be change if i use lable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
       [

           'lable'=>'practiceCode',
           'format' => 'raw',
           'value'=>function ($model, $index, $widget){
            return Html::a($model->practiceCode,['practice/view','id'=>$model->practiceCode],['title'=>'Go!','target'=>'_blank']
            );
    // return Html::a(Html::encode("View"),'practice/view');
   // return Html::a(Html::encode($data- >practiceCode),'practice/view');

        },
    ],
```

Comment: Please add at least minimal explanation of this code.

Comment: Here i want to open detail of practice after link on id it's work after click on id but CSS issue occur for displaying list i am using table and in table head name as link in CSS .table > thead > tr > th > a {
    color:white;
} but in my code i use label for displaying table head thats why i asked can i use 'a' tag instead of 'label'

Answer (score 1):

Now it's working `'attribute'=>'practiceCode'` instead of `'lable'=>'practiceCode',`